# Turn Windows laptop into iBeacon

Tags: windows, debugging, testing, ibeacon

I have a laptop with Bluetooth 4.0, or Bluetooth Low Energy if you will.

For testing purposes I'd like to turn this Windows 8 laptop into broadcasting a fake iBeacon UUID/MajorID/MinorID so I can test an App I wrote.

Is there any software available with which I can broadcast beacons? Or any API's or libraries with which I could (easily) write it myself?

Like this, but then for Windows: https://github.com/timd/MactsAsBeacon

An actual iBeacon is on its way here, but I'd love to already do some testing in the meanwhile.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So, it is possible, but you need a Linux VM inside Windows 8. Here's a small guide.

**Step 1: VirtualBox**

- Install VirtualBox and the VirtualBox Extention Pack, make sure they are the same version.
- Create new Ubuntu Linux VM, mount an ubuntu installation CD, and install the OS. I used the server edition since a GUI would be unnecessary and slow everything down.
- Make sure in the VM's settings the USB 2.0 controller is turned on, and you created a filter for your Bluetooth device.
- Then start your VM and in the running VM window, enable sharing your bluetooth device: Menu Devices > USB Devices > select Bluetooth device.

**Step 2: Linux**

Run:

```
sudo apt-get install bluez
sudo hciconfig hci0 up
sudo hciconfig hci0 leadv 3
sudo hciconfig hci0 noscan
hciconfig
```

The last command should show `UP RUNNING` before you continue.

If you can't find the `hci0` device, you probably have incorrect VM usb filter settings, or your device is in use by Windows. I found that disabling and enabling the device in the Windows Device Manager helped the VM recognize it. When you enabled sharing the bluetooth device from VirtualBox, the Device Manager should show a greyed-out bluetooth adapter when you've selected 'Shown hidden devices'.

**Step 3: Assemble your broadcast command**

1. Generate a UUID: `python -c 'import sys,uuid; sys.stdout.write(uuid.uuid4().hex)'`
2. The format of the command will be:

   1. `hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0008`
   2. `1E 02 01 1A 1A FF` (iBeacon-specific flags)
   3. Company ID, `4C 00` is Apple
   4. `02 15` (iBeacon advertisement indicator)
   5. UUID: 16 pairs of 2 hex numbers, separated by spaces
   6. Major ID: `00 00`
   7. Minor ID: `00 00`
   8. Calibrated Tx power: `C8 00`, or short: `C8`

Your command should look something like this, replace the `__` with your UUID:

```
sudo hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0008 1E 02 01 1A 1A FF 4C 00 02 15 __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ 00 00 00 00 C8
```

**Step 4: Start broadcasting!**

Example command:

```
sudo hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0008 1E 02 01 1A 1A FF 4C 00 02 15 63 6F 3F 8F 64 91 4B EE 95 F7 D8 CC 64 A8 63 B5 00 00 00 00 C8
```

If that command was succesful, it should keep transmitting. Grab your Android or iPhone device and install the *iBeacon locate* app to see if you can find your beacon broadcasted.

Happy app debugging!

Credits: a lot of the idea's were stolen from [this article](http://www.wadewegner.com/2014/05/create-an-ibeacon-transmitter-with-the-raspberry-pi/).

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, Windows 8 cannot transmit as a BLE beacon.  While Windows 8.1 does have BLE APIs, they can only be used to communicate with standard Bluetooth profile devices once paired.  Only the operating system can do the scanning and pairing.  This makes it impossible for third party apps to scan for beacons or transmits beacons.  We are hoping that Windows 9 will change this situation.

An alternative on Windows is to install virtual machine software like VirtualBox, and use a Linux virtual machine to do the transmitting.  There is a free example of this here: http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/altbeacon/virtual

Note that this example transmits intellectual property a free AltBeacon advertisements.  But it is trivial to modify the virtual machine's altbeacon_transmit script to transmit any other beacon format.  You can see the source code for the transmitter script here: https://github.com/RadiusNetworks/altbeacon-reference/blob/master/altbeacon_transmit

Answer (score 1):

There now is a managed C# library called [WinBeacon](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WinBeacon/) that does exactly that.